# The mathemathical physics behind punching things that hang

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, speed

How do you calculate the angle at which a hanging body will move when it is hit on it's hanging end?

Comment: How do you deal with situations in which you apply a force to an object that has a fixed point around which it can rotate?

Comment: Please provide a picture of the situation as well as details of what you mean. The question is too vague in its current wording.

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure out the kinetic energy transferred at impact. Then you can calculate the velocity of the object at that instance by inserting the mass of the hanging object in this formula. If instead you know the velocity of the hanging object at the moment of impact you can skip the first step.

$$K= \frac{mv^2}{2}$$

Rearranged:

$$v = \sqrt\frac{2K}{m}$$

All the kinetic energy will then transfer to potential energy. $h$ being the change in elevation.

$$\frac{mv^2}{2} = mgh$$

Rearranged:

$$h = \frac{v^2}{2g}$$

For the final step we use the pendulum equation to calculate the angle $θ$ with respect to $Δh$ and $l$. Where $l$ is the length of the string.

$$h = l(1-\cos θ)$$

Rearranged:

$$θ = \frac{180^\circ(2π - \cos^{-1}(1-\frac{h}{l}))}{π}$$

Answer (score 1):

When you punch something you transfer a certain amount of momentum to that object. How much you transfer will be worked out later. The exchange of momentum is called an impulse.

For now, an impulse of magnitude $J$ is transferred to kinetic energy first with  $$ {\rm KE} = \frac{J^2}{2\, m} \tag{1} $$

and then to potential energy

$$ {\rm PE} = m g c (1-\cos \theta) \tag{2} $$

But (1) is incorrect because the punching bag is attached to the ceiling. It has mass moment of inertia about the pivot of $I_A$ then

$$ {\rm KE} = \frac{J^2}{2 m_{\rm eff}} \tag{3} $$ with $m_{\rm eff} = \frac{I_A}{c^2}$ and $c$ the distance from the pivot to the center of mass.

So the balance of energy is

$$ \frac{J^2 c^2}{2 I_A} = c\,mg (1-\cos \theta) \tag{4}$$

which is solved for the swing angle $\theta = \cos^{-1} \left(1 - \frac{c \;J^2}{2 I_A m g} \right)$.

But what about the impulse magnitude $J$. Well, when you hit, it is not a force from the muscles that you apply, but the momentum of the swinging hand. This momentum is $J$. Each person has their own value of $J$ they can produce by punching.